# How to get the currently connected network from the command line?

Tags: python, cmd

I am creating a program in Python which connects to the host, FTPs the file I want over, and then connects to my previous network with `netsh wlan connect`. All of this works.

However, it has the downside of only being able to work while I am connected to one network. I'd like it to reconnect me to whatever network I was using before I connected to the FTP host.

Is there a way to get the name of the network I am currently connected to, in either Python or the Windows command line?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a wireless network? `netsh wlan show interfaces` will show you.

Comment: Cool -- this is pretty much what I was looking for. How can I get it to just show the SSID though?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
connected_ssid = subprocess.check_output("powershell.exe (get-netconnectionProfile).Name", shell=True).strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

current_network = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'interfaces']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
ssid_line = [x for x in current_network if 'SSID' in x and 'BSSID' not in x]
if ssid_line:
    ssid_list = ssid_line[0].split(':')
    connected_ssid = ssid_list[1].strip()
    print(connected_ssid)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a messy way, here is something that worked for me. Note, I think this method assumes that SSID 1 has the strongest signal, might not necessarily be the one you're looking for.

```
import subprocess
network_Information = str(subprocess.check_output(["netsh","wlan","show","network"]))
network_Information = network_Information.replace('\\r','')
network_Information = network_Information.replace("b' ",'')
network_Information = network_Information.replace(":",'\n')
network_Information = network_Information.replace("\\n",'\n')
network_Information = network_Information.splitlines()
WIFINetworkNameString = network_Information[6][1:]
```

Comment: After running multiple times the resulted SSID is varying

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
joerg@dilbert:~$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netifaces as ni
>>> ni.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0', 'lxcbr0']
```

Comment: It's very ambiguous, but I think the OP is asking how to find out what WiFi access point is currently connected in Windows.